# Requested property name of a value that is not an object - while fetching data from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to the `react-native` world. I am using the following code to get a response from server. While debugging it is working fine, but without debugging it gives below error

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
fetch("http://hcdsny.trantorinc.com/index.php/api/register", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          body:  JSON.stringify(data)
          })
          .then(function(response){
            return response.json();   
          })
          .then(function(data){

          }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          });
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue and solved it by replacing **headers** with an object instead of a string.

Try this.

Replace (Header as a String)

```
headers: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

with (Header as a Object)

```
 headers: {      
    'Accept': 'application/json',     
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'   
 }
```

It may work for you.

Comment: @Navdeep Glad to hear you found your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Headers should be an object, not a string. The key for the header you are looking for is `content-type`:

```
headers: {
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```